# React range slider with two handles

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a range slider with two handles. Its main purpose is to filter the array of cars that I fetch from the server. Should I use library for the slider? I managed to almost get it done without any library. Here is the minimal working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-poincare-4kzcvy?file=/src/Slider.js

I seem to get it wrong in regard to calculations, since the red part of rail doesn't follow up precisely when dragging a handle, and the min value matches the full max value if dragged to the end.

```
//destructive props
const RangeSlider = ({ classes, label, onChange, value, ...sliderProps }) => {
     //set initial value to 0 this will change inside useEffect in first render also| or you can directly set useState(value)
    const [sliderVal, setSliderVal] = useState(0);

    // keep mouse state to determine whether i should call parent onChange or not.
    // so basically after dragging the slider and then release the mouse then we will call the parent onChange, otherwise parent function will get call each and every change
    const [mouseState, setMouseState] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      setSliderVal(value); // set new value when value gets changed, even when first render
    }, [value]);

    const changeCallback = (e) => {
      setSliderVal(e.target.value); // update local state of the value when changing
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      if (mouseState === "up") {
        onChange(sliderVal)// when mouse is up then call the parent onChange
      }
    }, [mouseState])

    return (
      <div className="range-slider">
        <p>{label}</p>
        <h3>value: { sliderVal }</h3>
        <input
          type="range"
          value={sliderVal}
          {...sliderProps}
          className={`slider ${classes}`}
          id="myRange"
          onChange={changeCallback}
          onMouseDown={() => setMouseState("down")} // When mouse down set the mouseState to 'down'
          onMouseUp={() => setMouseState("up")} // When mouse down set the mouseState to 'up' | now we can call the parent onChnage
        />
      </div>
    );
};

export default memo(RangeSlider);
```

I tried it this way but it doesnt add up to the solution when having two handles.

Comment: better to use a library for that, i suggest `multi-range-slider-react`